# plotly trace not displayed when it meets top of the chart

Tags: plotly.js

I am using Plotly JS with Java application to display statistics about latencies. I found that when the trace touches/meets the top of the chart, a part of the trace is not displayed at all.

[image]

While most of the trace that touches the top of the chart is visible. What could be the reason? How to fix it?

I am using plotly-basic-1.16.2.min.js. Tried with the latest version also - plotly-basic-latest.min.js. It didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting yAxis range property:

```
<Plot
        ...
        layout={{ yaxis: {range: [0.95, 1.1]} }}

      />
```

Since your data ranges from 0.95 to 1, setting maximum range to 1.1 might fix the problem.